# office 365のaccessでコールグラフを取得したい

Tags: ms-access

office 365のaccessで使われているVBAのコードに対してコールグラフ（関数の呼び出し関係）を取得したいです。
手動でコールグラフを作るのはかなり大変なので、専用のツールなどありますでしょうか？

Comment: Access VBAで使えるか分かりませんが、こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Excel VBAの開発環境に絶望したので2021年のモダンな環境を構築する](https://blog.ue-y.me/vba2021/), [VBAにはユニットテストやリファクタリング機能がない・・・そんなふうに考えていた時期が俺にもありました](https://qiita.com/mima_ita/items/3629006163d0a7fa6e55), [VBA開発環境をモダンにする - RubberduckとVBEThemeColorEditorの紹介](https://qiita.com/mochimo/items/e9be36619a76e15bc898), [VBA基礎５'：VS CODEでVBAを編集（XVBA）](https://note.com/kiyo_ai_note/n/n9653e7238c49), [VBA コード 分析 解析 ツール 【 マクロツリーXL 】](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/business/se523152.html)